# Rails JS assets not present in production (Heroku)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, production-environment

Building a Rails 7 app, which works fine in development. When uploading to Heroku, JS doesn't work and no JS is in the asset folder and I get the following errors. CSS works fine:

```
2022-12-31T09:21:44.860222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/bootstrap" host=xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=27e5c00d-8913-46da-a510-7d975f12a31f fwd="194.191.238.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2022-12-31T09:21:44.857991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/controllers" host=xxx.herokuapp.com request_id=d227fc0d-4cd3-4e24-8586-9e8912316bb9 fwd="194.191.238.4" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
```

I am using Rails 7.0.4 with standard settings (incl. Import Maps). Any suggestions? Thanks!

The only "solution" so far is to set the following to "true", which is not a valid fix.

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Setting the following to "true" did not bring any results.

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not a valid fix"?

Comment: I am no rails expert - In the conversation where I found this fix, it was mentioned that this would be a significant security issue - Isn't that true?

Comment: No, that's not why assets are compiled. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Well, the "not a valid fix" worked for me....so thanks!